# Line drawing algorithm with one pixel per scanline

Tags: c, algorithm, drawing, line

I am looking for a line drawing algorithm that only plots one pixel per scanline/row and only use integers.

Bresenham line drawing algorithm works in most of the cases, but it plots two pixel per scanline when I have a line from P1(40, 0) to P2(0, 20) where Pn(x, y).

For the record, I'm coding in C for a low end micro controller with no floating point unit.

Thanks!

Comment: And what do you want to happen if you have a horizontal (or almost horizontal) line? Bresenham's algorithm plots multiple pixels in a row if that's what is required to get a good representation. Any time the difference between X1 and X2 is greater than the distance between Y1 and Y2, you're going to get multiple pixels on one or more scan lines. Seems like you could easily modify your Bresenham implementation to keep track of the Y position of the last pixel plotted, and not plot the next pixel if it's the same Y coordinate.

Comment: That is how I've implemented, but I thought it might be some algorithm out there which is faster than my modified Bresenham. Because I can't be the first one who want such a line drawing algorithm. And for your question, it should only plot one pixel for a horizontal line.

Answer (score 0):

To simulate floating point you can scale the integers, so in stead of "1" you have "1000" where you imagine the floating point after the third digit from the left. Then you perform Bresenham's algorithm in integer on these scaled values. Once calculated, you de-scale by integer division with this maximum. You may want to round. You must determine the maximum x value and choose your scale acordingly. Taking a power of 2, you can use shift in stead of divisision.

To ensue there will be only one pixel per line, you can use a cut-off value, where below will not draw the pixel and above will. The pixel should be drawn as black (or white) but there are no gradients (as otherwise you need two pixels).

Comment: Yeah, I could use fixed point to represent floating point but I think that solution will be much more slow than Bresenham.

Comment: I said: use Brensham but using integer arithmatic. That is always faster than floating point.  You said you don't have an FPU.

Comment: Sorry sorry! I was in a hurry before... Anywho, looks like I stick with the Bresenham with the y-modification. But I still wonder if I'm the only one who wants this sort of line drawing algorithm. It does not feel that optimized. And I believe that this sort of algorithm was useful back in the day in the eighties when people wanted to plot polygons with co-cpus.

Answer (score 0):

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham's_line_algorithm:

"*...This results in an algorithm that uses only integer arithmetic.*"